# The name 'xxxxx' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola amigos tengo un detalle con un proyecto estoy intentando generar un reporte de días trabajados y faltas, pero en los errores me dice que no existen algunas cosas en el contexto actual, soy nueva con esto de c# este proyecto ya estaba hecho, solo me lo dieron para hacer unas modificaciones pero al momento que lo abro en visual studio 2010 me marca esos errores, estoy utilizando el 2010 ya que fue el que me dijeron, por ser un proyecto ya viejito.

Absences.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="Reporte de días trabajados y faltas" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Absences.aspx.cs" Inherits="Absences" %>

    <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

    <%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">    
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
      <p style="color:Navy;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold">Días trabajados y faltas</p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Departamento: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbDepartment" runat="server" Height="44px" Width="257px" 
            DataSourceID="sourceDepartment" DataTextField="DeptName" 
            DataValueField="DeptID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Todos" AutoPostBack="True" 
            oncheckedchanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceDepartment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ZKTimeConnection%>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ZKTimeConnection.providerName%>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DeptID, DeptName FROM DBTime.departments Where status = 0;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <div>
            Fecha inicial:
            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="pickerFirstDate" Runat="server" Culture="es-MX" 
                MinDate="2017-01-01" Width="228px">
                <calendar usecolumnheadersasselectors="False" userowheadersasselectors="False" 
                    viewselectortext="x">
                </calendar>
                <dateinput dateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" displaydateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" labelwidth="">
                </dateinput>
                <datepopupbutton hoverimageurl="" imageurl="" />
            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
            Fecha final:
            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="pickerSecondDate" Runat="server" Culture="es-MX" 
                MinDate="2017-01-01" Width="228px">
                <calendar usecolumnheadersasselectors="False" userowheadersasselectors="False" 
                    viewselectortext="x">
                </calendar>
                <dateinput dateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" displaydateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" labelwidth="">
                </dateinput>
                <datepopupbutton hoverimageurl="" imageurl="" />
            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
            <br />
            Días laborables del periodo:
            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtWorkingDays" Runat="server" 
                Culture="es-MX" LabelWidth="" Value="6" Width="125px" 
                EmptyMessage="Ingrese los días que deberían considerarse laborables dentro del periodo" 
                MaxValue="100" MinValue="0">
<NumberFormat ZeroPattern="n" DecimalDigits="0"></NumberFormat>
            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <br />
            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" onclick="btnGenerate_Click" 
                Text="Generar Reporte">
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </p>
<p>
        </p>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="903px" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="765px" 
        InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
        WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>    
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AbsencesDataSource" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="Select" TypeName="AbsencesLoader">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pickerFirstDate" Name="firstDate" 
                PropertyName="SelectedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pickerSecondDate" Name="secondDate" 
                PropertyName="SelectedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbDepartment" Name="departmentId" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="chkAll" Name="isForAllEmployees" 
                PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />       
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    
    <p>
         <a href="http://mipagina.com"  title="DB Time">    
         Regresar a sistema de tiempo y asistencia</a>.
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
         </asp:ScriptManager>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Absences.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

public partial class Absences : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (!IsPostBack) 
      {            
      }
}
protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbDepartment.Enabled = !chkAll.Checked;
}

protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblNotes.Visible = false;

    if (validations()) 
    {
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "AbsencesReport.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource reportSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportSource.DataSourceId = "AbsencesDataSource";
        reportSource.Name = "DBTimeDS_Absences";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportSource);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("WorkingDays", txtWorkingDays.Value.ToString()));
        ReportViewer1.DataBind();            
    }
}

private bool validations()
{
    if (!pickerFirstDate.SelectedDate.HasValue || !pickerSecondDate.SelectedDate.HasValue)
    {
        lblNotes.Text = "Debe seleccionar la fecha inicial y final";
        lblNotes.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
    else if (pickerFirstDate.SelectedDate > pickerSecondDate.SelectedDate)
    {
        lblNotes.Text = "La fecha inicial no puede ser posterior a la fecha final";
        lblNotes.Visible = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
 }
```

Estos son los errores que me manda
[image: errores]

En modo diseño:
[image: diseño]

Referencias:

[image: referencias]

Comment: En modo diseñador si están los componentes?

Comment: Hola @Bicho acabo de agregar una imagen de cómo se ve en modo diseño

Comment: Observo que usa componentes de terceros como es el caso de `telerik`, tienes esos componentes instalados en la PC de desarrollo? Si es asi cerra todas las pestañas de codigo y diseñador, luego realiza un Rebuild de la solucion, no un build sino un rebuild y valida que compila sin errores

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini sí tengo Telerik instalado pero ya hice lo que comentas pero sigue sin funcionar :(

Answer (score 0):

esto sucede a veces cuando copias un proyecto los objetos no se pasan con el mismo nombre, y cambia por el nombre que trae de defecto, en cuanto a los reportviewer tienes que instalar algunos NuGet para que te funcione y tambien complementos de base de datos que los descargas atraves de visual studio intaller, para que reportviewer te funcione debes instalar los nuget siguientes, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common,

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms y
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,
espero te sirva

Comment: Hola @sam0221 acabo de añadir las referencias que tengo,te cuento, me pasaron ese proyecto para hacer una actualización pero el proyecto no tenía una solución entonces no lo podía abrir en Visual Studio, asi que cree un nuevo proyecto y copie los archivos, pero si ves en la captura del archivo Absences.aspx ahí sí vienen los campos que se solicitan en el Absences.aspx.cs :/